# Keyup and keydown events on paragraph not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

My html -

```
<div id="test">
  <p contenteditable="true"></p>
  <p contenteditable="true"></p>
  <p contenteditable="true"></p>     
</div>
```

My jquery

```
var typingTimer;                
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;  

$("#test p").each(function() {

   $(this).on('keyup', function() {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    });


  $(this).on('keydown', function() {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  });
}


//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping () {
    alert("ready to save");
}
```

I need to execute some function when user stops typing in a paragraph. The above code doesnt seem to work. Thanks in advance
JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/etJ3Q/20/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in your code, each isn't closed properly, which is why it isn't working.

Just open the console and you will see the errors...

You can also avoid using each.

http://jsfiddle.net/etJ3Q/29/

```
var typingTimer;                
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;

$("#test p")
    .on('keyup', function() {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    })
    .on('keydown', function() {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping () {
    alert("ready to save");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is better and works...

```
var typingTimer;                
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;  

$("#test p").on('keyup', function() {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
}).on('keydown', function() {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});


//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping () {
    alert("ready to save");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't explain what was wrong with his code though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the loop, just directly assign the functions to #test paragraphs

```
var typingTimer;                
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;  

$("#test p").on('keyup', function() {
clearTimeout(typingTimer);
typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});


$("#test p").on('keydown', function() {
clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping () {
    alert("ready to save");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9ELLV/)

```
$("#test p").each(function() {

   $(this).on('keyup', function() {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    });


  $(this).on('keydown', function() {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Will it be nice if we use a focusout event of jQuery. After typing in the paragraph, when it loses focus we can excecute the function. I am sorry if I am wrong. If somebody stops typing for a moment then the alert will be shown. Using focusout we can avoid that.

```
$("#test p").focusout(function(){ 
   //$(this).hide(); 
   doneTyping (); 
   //setTimeout(alertHello(),3000); 
   //clearTimeout(); 
});
```

Comment: This is my code. Please check.

$("#test p").focusout(function(){
     //$(this).hide();
     doneTyping ();
     //setTimeout(alertHello(),3000);
     //clearTimeout();
    });